# jquery find the class of a parent

Tags: jquery

I need to assign a variable with the class of the parent's div.

This is the HTML:

```
<li class="task" id="task_10">
  <div class="10">
    <a href="/tasks/10">
      David Smith
      :
      Demo for Joe
      <br>
    </a><a href="#" rel="taskpopup" id="taskpopup" data-bb="confirm" class="bb-dialog btn-small btn-primary">Update</a>                      
  </div>
</li>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$("[rel=taskpopup]").click(function() {
  return bootbox.prompt("New Update:", function(result) {
  var taskid;
  if (result === null) {
    return 'false';
  } else {
    taskid = $(this).parent.className;
...
```

What's not working is the line:

```
taskid = $(this).parent.className;
```

What should it be?

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery hybrid: `taskid = $(this).parent()[0].className;`
Pure Javascript: `taskid = this.parentNode.className`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to be using jQuery, why not use this (jQuery) way :

```
taskid = $(this).parent().attr("class");
```

And here's how you do it with JavaScript (if that's what you really want) :

```
taskid = this.parentNode.className
```

**EDIT**

You could also use `closest`.

```
taskid = $(this).closest("div").attr("class");
```

Comment: Note that your plain js version will result in undefined if the parent node is not an element node (that's why my answer uses `parentElement`).

Comment: Actually, your version makes more sense... I can't think of a realistic scenario where the *parent* would be another kind of node...

Comment: Thanks for the help!  But, using `taskid = $(this).parent().attr("class")`, I'm getting "undefined".  Is the div, the parent?

Comment: I updated my question with more HTML.  The HTML for the whole page is quite large.  It contains a bunch of <ul> with <li>.

Answer (score 2):

What you were trying is actually closer to the non-jQuery solution:

```
this.parentNode.className;
```

or:

```
this.parentElement.className;
```

Comment: I wonder why people are looking to slow those simple queries using jQuery. Good job on the pureJS.

Answer (score 0):

First, the syntax which you were using the parent className was wrong.
Second, you call $(this) under function of  bootbox.prompt.
You should set it before.

```
$("[rel=taskpopup]").click(function() {
var selector = $(this);
  return bootbox.prompt("New Update:", function(result) {
  var taskid;
  if (result === null) {
    return 'false';
  } else {
    taskid = $(selector).parent().attr("class");
```